# Powershell loop through CSV Compare Email to ActiveDirectory

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

If I run this script without the look and manually enter say my email for the section of `(mail=myaddress@someplace.com)` it works and says `User found in AD` but when I run this script to loop through it comes back with the full list of email addresses with `User does not exist in AD` preceding the email address as if it cannot find the email address in AD.

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

```
$path = "H:\users.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv $path 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

foreach($line in $csv)
{
    $User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$line.Email))"
    If ($User -eq $Null) {"User does not exist in AD   " + $line.Email }
    Else {"User found in AD  - " + $line.Email}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use subexpression `$()` when accessing the email property in our ldap-filter. Try this:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($line.Email)))"
```

Subexpressions are required when your accessing a more custom value then a pure string variable(like a property of an object).

Comment: I will try this first thing in the morning. I sure hope this works it will save me SOOO much time trying to verify if these 300 plus users are still valid.

Comment: Ansgar: good catch with the typo! At least my sample was correct :)

Comment: Thank you so much I just tested this and it appears to be working perfectly